# не могу залогинится

Tags: asp.net-core

https://www.screencast.com/t/mnuvefv4CMO8

code

```
if (this._signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName.ToLower(), model.Password, false, false).Result.Succeeded)
```

Exception
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.SqlServerStringReplaceTranslator' threw an exception.

InnerException

Sequence contains more than one matching element

StackTrace

at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.SqlServerStringReplaceTranslator..cctor()

Comment: проблемма в .net core 2.0 версиюю в проекте нужно было оставить 1.1 и nuget вернуть на старые версии 1.1.2 и так далее